# How do you create a dynamic table in Excel that gets its data from multiple other tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

This is a bit of an edge case and I've seen several similar issues but nothing quite like this.

I have 3 tables of data and I'd like to create a master table with various parts of each table. As I add data to a sub table it should populate to the master.

IE:

Small Cars table
Medium Cars table
Large Cars table

Each table contains various cars of varying colors. Say Small Cars table has a Red, Yellow and Blue column and for each car in the table there's an x in one (or more) of the color columns.

I want a "Red Cars" table that is a collection of the RED cars from all 3 of the above tables. In this case "red car" would just be an 'x' in a column called Red.

Can this even be done? I've found ways to merge tables together and add rows from one table to another but not to create this sort of relationship.

Comment: Your question is bit confusing,, let me ask that literally your are handling TABLES or are Database in various Ranges in sheet like RED CAR TABLE has Range `A1:C10`,, if  not is an Excel TABLE,, better share some sample data and expected data with Master Table,, what you are expecting is possible using an Array Command/Function.

Comment: You can use Power Query to get the result, you can provide a sample of 3 tables about your problem. I can help you.